# If server is moved to different network, does it affect the SSH keys?

Tags: ip, ssh-keys

I had to move my server to a different network couple of days age. I don't know if I need to update the SSH keys or anything related to that on the server. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to change the keys if you don't have any reason to believe they were compromised.

If you always connect to the host via its DNS hostname, your SSH clients probably won't notice any difference. If you connect via IP address, and now the server is at a different IP address, then your clients will ask if you want to trust this host, as if they were connecting to a new host.

Comment: Thanks Spiff for your help. The IP is changed too. I also have some client machines in my office which SSH to this host. So all I need is to ssh once from these clients to the host and trust the host, right? :-)   Or to update the trusted IPs...

Comment: Yes, for each host that connects by IP address, SSH to the new IP address once in order to get past the host key trust prompt.